# Disable server side of asp.net button

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

How to disable button callback, I want to use this button on client side only?

```
<dx:ASPxButton ID="btn_clear" runat="server" 
    Text="Clear" Width="90px" OnClick="btn_clear_Click">
    <ClientSideEvents Click = "OnClick" />
</dx:ASPxButton>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hwo about simply removing the OnClick Handler ?

```
<dx:ASPxButton ID="btn_clear" runat="server" 
    Text="Clear" Width="90px">
    <ClientSideEvents Click = "OnClick" />
</dx:ASPxButton>
```

Or even better, just use a HTML button in the first place (`<input type="button" />`).

Comment: First option solved it, in combination with "Autopostback = false".

Answer (score 4):

`onClientClick=return false` will prevent processing the normal postback. If you want to do some custome javascript at client side, you can call return false after that

```
<asp:Button id="btn1" runat="server" onClientClick="return MyFunction" />
```

And in javascript

```
function MyFunction()
{
  //Do your custom code

 return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Judging by your button tag prefix it looks as though you're using Devexpress components not a normal asp.net button. Devexpress' `ASPxButton` control client click event has a `processOnServer` property which you can set to false to prevent a postback:

```
<dx:ASPxButton ID="btn_clear" runat="server" 
    Text="Clear" Width="90px" OnClick="btn_clear_Click">
    <ClientSideEvents Click = "OnClick" />
</dx:ASPxButton>
```

and your `OnClick()` javascript function:

```
function OnClick(s, e)
{
        e.processOnServer = false;
}
```

Without using third party components, if you want a button to just do something client side, then just use a HTML input button but if you want to have the client side capabilities of the asp.net button at your disposal (such as causing validation) then [Shyju's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10364978/189756) is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

Server side controls **must** run on the server side.

If you omit the `runat="server"` attribute, the markup will render **exactly** like this:

```
<dx:ASPxButton ID="btn_clear" 
    Text="Clear" Width="90px" OnClick="btn_clear_Click">
    <ClientSideEvents Click = "OnClick" />
</dx:ASPxButton>
```

This will be completely ignored by the browser, as an element `dx:ASPxButton` is not a valid HTML element.

Comment: I dont want it to do callbacks.

Comment: @elninho - Then remove the server side events such as the `OnClick`. I suggest _reading_ the documentation on the specific control.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an attribute AutoPostBack="false", this will stop the postback, still you need to call server side function using client side script, you can use callback panels